# Pasar objeto entero

Tags: angular

Necesito pasar toda la información que tiene un objeto y sacar sus valores pero no consigo hacerlo. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ng-select placeholder="Seleciona grupo" [virtualScroll] [(ngModel)]='addgrupo'>
            <ng-option value="">Seleciona grupo</ng-option>
            <ng-option *ngFor="let fgrupos of nombreGrupoIden" value="{{fgrupos}}">{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}} - {{fgrupos.nombre_grupo}}</ng-option>
    </ng-select>
    {{addgrupo.nombre_grupo}}
</div>
```

Tengo mi ngModel que se llama addgrupo al cual le paso el objeto de fgrupos, lo intento sacar como addgrupo.nombregrupo y no me saca nada.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
<ng-select placeholder="Seleciona grupo" [virtualScroll] [(ngModel)]='addgrupo'>
        <ng-option value="">Seleciona grupo</ng-option>
        <ng-option *ngFor="let fgrupos of nombreGrupoIden" [ngValue]="fgrupos">{{fgrupos.identificador_grupo}} - {{fgrupos.nombre_grupo}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
{{addgrupo.nombre_grupo}}
```

Comment: Lo tengo igual, pero no me funcionó